# String annotations of Python fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, annotations

Does Python support any type of string annotation for class fields?  For example, in Golang, I can define a structure like this, with an optional string tag:

```
type User struct {
    Name string `example:"name"`
}
```

I need to define a new class in Python, which contains fields names that contain a dot `.`.  I was hoping that there may be some way to annotate a field, or define a "tag" in the same manner, so that when a field is accessed and written out, it will (or can) show the dot annotation.

This obviously isn't allowed in Python:

```
class MyNetworkClass(TypedDict):
    network.client.ip: str
    network.client.port: int
```

So I need a class where I can define valid field names, but return the dot annotation.

So I'd need something like the following, with valid field names, but some sort of tag/annotation/label/whatever...

```
class MyNetworkClass(TypedDict):
    network_client_ip: str "network.client.ip"
    network_client_port: int "network.client.port"
```

Note, I'm not looking for the dot annotation to be the **value** of the field, but rather the output string for the field name when printed.

Comment: Attribute names (and any other type of name) can not contain a period.

Comment: Yep, that's what I say in my question.